# jquery Cycle advanced slide

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

I'm using jQuery cycle plugin http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/ and I am trying to create similar slider effect like on this page http://themeforest.net/item/doover-premium-wordpress-theme/full_screen_preview/2279114
It mean's that the title and descriptions slide from different sides in different time. They are using jQuery cycle slider too.

I don't have any idea how to do it. Any advice would be nice and I would be glad for it.

Here is my HTML Code: https://gist.github.com/2697871

Here is my CSS code: https://gist.github.com/2697874

Here is my JS code: https://gist.github.com/2697877

Thx for your time.

Answer (score 1):

First, in **javascript**, set the current slide class to active.
Then, in **Css** set your elements positions absolute outside your slide

```
.title{position:absolute; top:0; left:100%; }
.text{position:absolute; top:0; left:-100%;}
```

Finally, in Css, add an animation when there parent is set to active

```
.active .title{animation: animateTitle 2s 1 ease-out forwards;}
.active .text{animation: animateText 2s 1 ease-out forwards;}

@keyframes animateTitle {
    0%   { left: 100%; }
    100% { left: 0; }
}

@keyframes animateTtext {
    0%   { left: -100%; }
    100% { left: 0; }
}
```

Comment: and how can I set the current slide class to active pls?

Comment: So I add .active class and I add your css but it seems that .title and .text are out of the "li item" now.. and don't do any animation.... Here is my file https://www.dropbox.com/s/brp5kwi11j4s8jh/cycle%20slider.rar

Comment: Because I set the animation without any prefixe -webkit, -moz, -ms, -o. You'll need to add those to your code